# File does not exist when data obtained from os

Tags: python, windows, operating-system

I'm trying to add a list of image locations into a list for each parent folder for image comparison. However when I pull the list of images from the folders with OS and then check them from the list with os.path.exists, some of the paths apparently do not exist, even though the files do exist when i manually check.

How do I fix this or work out why it is now saying the file paths do not exist? I have already tried to strip out white spaces

```py
import os

directory = '$$$'
listFiles = os.listdir(directory)
tester = []
for entry in listFiles:
    fullpath = os.path.join(directory, entry)
    test = fullpath
    listFiles = os.listdir(fullpath)
    print(listFiles)
    for n in listFiles:
        fullpath = os.path.join(test,n)
        fullpath = fullpath.strip()
        tester.append(fullpath)
    for n in range (len(tester)):

        print(tester[n].strip())
        print(os.path.exists(tester[n]))



    break
```

Comment: What 's  operating system you are using ?, i.e. if you are using `Linux`, file with a name, `data file` is `'data file' ` , if you replace spaces with a delimiter `file-name`, then it's the same.

Comment: I'm using windows

Comment: remove `.strip()`, it's usless and might be the problem as `os.listdir`, returns the directory content (files, sub-directories), exactly with the same format

Comment: Code wasn't working before strip was added. I only added strip in as a lot of the files that return as not existing have a lot of spaces in them so I presumed it may be the white spaces causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

`.strip()` doesn't remove **whitespaces** everywhere, just and the **beginning** and the **end** of the string.

---

Try to rename your directory content removing spaces everywhere, or it's better to rename it to a short string (ex. `a number`)

```
dir = '....'
content = os.listdir(dir)

for i in range(len(content)):

  path = os.path.join(dir, content[i])
  # if file to number : new_path = path + '/' + i + '.' + os.path.splitext(content[i])[-1]
  new_path = path.replace(' ', '') 

  print(path, new_path)

  os.rename(path, new_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to append all the files in the directory to the list `tester`, including subdirectories. If you're using `os.listdir()`, you need to then recursively run that on all the entries which are also dirs, perhaps by using [`is_dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry.is_dir). But instead of writing all that by hand, just use [**`os.walk()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) which already recurses folders:

```
directory = '$$$'
tester = []
for parent, folders, files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
        tester.append(os.path.join(parent, file))

print(tester)
```

That can be shortened to:

```
directory = '$$$'
tester = [os.path.join(parent, file)
              for parent, folders, files in os.walk(directory)
              for file in files]
```

Note: Spaces in filenames or folders don't matter when using such functions. If you were trying to execute something on command line, then spaces matter and require quoting or escaping.